# cannot find function `concat_str` in this scope | Rust Polars

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I've read a csv file and I'm trying to concatenate three columns that I cast the data type string, to create a new column called identifier

I'm using 0.37.0

```
use polars::prelude::*;
use polars_lazy::dsl::functions::*;

let df_x = df_a.clone()
    .lazy()
    .select([
        col("id_turn").cast(DataType::String),
        col("id_room").cast(DataType::String),
        col("id_course").cast(DataType::String)
    ])
    .collect()?;
    
    let mut df_y = df_x.clone()
    .lazy()
    .with_column([
        all(),
        concat_str([col("id_turn"), col("id_room"), col("id_course")],"_",true).alias("identifier")
    ])
    .collect()
    .unwrap();
```

but I keep getting this error[E0425]: cannot find function `concat_str` in this scope

Thanks in advance

I've try this in python polars and it works fine

```
df_x = df_a.with_columns(
    pl.concat_str(
        [
            pl.col("id_turn"),
            pl.col("id_room"),
            pl.col("id_course"),
        ],
        separator="_",
    ).alias("uuid"),

)
```

Comment: Can you update your code with imports?

Comment: Have you enabled the concat_str feature? Per the documentation: "Available on crate features concat_str and strings and lazy only."
https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/fn.concat_str.html

Comment: @jvanbuel I've tried this imports:

use polars::prelude::*;
use polars_lazy::dsl::functions::*;

Comment: Please add the complete error message (from `cargo build`) as formated text to the question, not just the short excerpt your IDE might give you.

Answer (score 2):

[`polars::prelude::concat_str`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/fn.concat_str.html) is only available with the `concat_str` *and* `strings` *and* `lazy` [features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) enabled. Are you sure all these features are enabled in your `Cargo.toml` file?

```
[dependencies]
polars = { version = "0.37", features = ["concat_str", "strings", "lazy"] }
```